# How to load array of data in table view when tap on Next button in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, uitableview

i trying load array item details in tableview. In tableview, i have listed array of labels. And placed two button on navigation bar namely **Next** and **previous**

When user tap on next it will replace array label values in tableview or if user tap on previous it will replace array label values in tableview.

For getting data from json i'm using SwiftyJson. here is my json response value:

```
    "results": [
  {

   "PoDocNo": "4500022400",
   "Item": "00010",
   "Material": "RMECC_MOB1",
   "StorageLocation": "3001",
   "MatGroup": "00107",
    "Quantity": "2.000",
   "OrderUnit": "KG",
   "NetPrice": "1000.000",
   "UnitofPrice": "1.000",
   "ItemCat": "0",
   "Requistor": ""
   },
   {

   "PoDocNo": "4500022400",
   "Item": "00020",
    "Material": "RMECC_MOB1",
    "StorageLocation": "3001",
   "MatGroup": "00107",
   "Quantity": "2.000",
   "OrderUnit": "KG",
   "NetPrice": "1000.000",
   "UnitofPrice": "1.000",
   "ItemCat": "0",
   "Requistor": ""
   }
  ]
```

Here is my screenshot of screen:  [image]

Here is my model:

```
    import Foundation
    import SwiftyJSON

   class PoVendorModel {

   var Material: String?
    var Description: String?
   var FixedVendor: String?
var VendorName: String?
var PurchOrg: String?
var PurchGroup : String?
var valuationPrice : String?
var Qty: String?
var UoM:String?

var totalValue: String?
var DeliveryDate: String?
var MatGrp: String?
var Plant: String?
var StorageLocation: String?
var ReqTrack: String?
var AAC: String?
var ItemCategory: String?
var GLAccount: String?
var CostCenter: String?
var Order: String?
var WBS: String?
var ProfitCenter: String?
var lineNo: String?

init(json: JSON) {

    Material = json["Material"].stringValue
    Qty = json["Quantity"].stringValue
    UoM = json["OrderUnit"].stringValue
    totalValue = json["NetPrice"].stringValue
    AAC = json["shrtText"].stringValue
    StorageLocation = json["StorageLocation"].stringValue
    MatGrp = json["MatGroup"].stringValue
    valuationPrice = json["NetPrice"].stringValue
    ItemCategory = json["ItemCat"].stringValue

    lineNo = json["Item"].stringValue

}

func getProperty(at index: Int) -> String {

    switch index {
    case 0:
        return self.Material ?? ""
    case 1:
        return self.Description ?? ""
    case 2:
        return self.FixedVendor ?? ""
    case 3:
        return self.VendorName ?? ""
    case 4:
        return self.PurchOrg ?? ""
    case 5:
        return self.PurchGroup ?? ""
    case 6:
        return self.Qty ?? ""
    case 7:
        return self.valuationPrice ?? ""
    case 8:
        return self.totalValue ?? ""
    case 9:
        return self.DeliveryDate ?? ""
    case 10:
        return self.MatGrp ?? ""
    case 11:
        return self.Plant ?? ""
    case 12:
        return self.StorageLocation ?? ""
    case 13:
        return self.ReqTrack ?? ""
    case 14:
        return self.AAC ?? ""
    case 15:
        return self.ItemCategory ?? ""
    case 16:
        return self.GLAccount ?? ""
    case 17:
        return self.CostCenter ?? ""
    case 18:
        return self.Order ?? ""
    case 19:
        return self.WBS ?? ""
    case 20:
        return self.ProfitCenter ?? ""
    case 21:
        return self.UoM ?? ""

    default:
        return "Error"
    }

  }

 }
```

How can i replace array of values when i tap on next button in label values in tableview?

Comment: Consider using `Codable` - it will help you get rid of all those optional properties and the need for providing defaults (e.g. `return self.PurchGroup ?? ""`) will go away.

Comment: 1. Update the values in your datasource, 2. call `reloadData()` on your `UITableView`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever object handles your "Next" and "Previous" clicks should be aware of all of your data and the current "page" number. Give your tableView a property of type `PoVendorModel` (if it hasn't already got one). Tapping Next or Previous can update the page number, index into the array of models and assign the relevant one to the tableView. The tableView can react to that and update itself when the value is changed.

In whatever handles next/previous clicks:

```
var allVendors: [PoVendorModel]

var pageNumber: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        tableViewController.vendorData = allVendors[pageNumber]
    }
}

func nextTapped() {
    pageNumber = min(allVendors.count - 1, pageNumber + 1)
}

func previousTapped() {
    pageNumber = max(0, pageNumber - 1)
}
```

In your UITableViewController:

```
// A property of your UITableViewController
var vendorData: PoVendorModel? = nil {
    didSet {
        tableView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of manually parsing all the *JSON response*, use `Codable` instead.

The **model** you should create,

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let vendors: [PoVendorModel]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case vendors = "results"
    }
}

struct PoVendorModel: Decodable {
    let poDocNo, item, material, storageLocation, matGroup, quantity, orderUnit, netPrice, unitofPrice, itemCat, requistor: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case poDocNo = "PoDocNo"
        case item = "Item"
        case material = "Material"
        case storageLocation = "StorageLocation"
        case matGroup = "MatGroup"
        case quantity = "Quantity"
        case orderUnit = "OrderUnit"
        case netPrice = "NetPrice"
        case unitofPrice = "UnitofPrice"
        case itemCat = "ItemCat"
        case requistor = "Requistor"
    }
}
```

**Parse** the *JSON data* using the above created models,

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
        self.vendors = root.vendors //created in viewController
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

In the `ViewController`, create properties for `vendors` and the `dataSource` instance you'll be using for `tableView's` `dataSource`. Also, maintain a `currentIndex` that'll keep track of the current `vendor` visible in the `tableView`.

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var currentIndex: Int = 0

    var vendors = [PoVendorModel]() {
        didSet {
            self.dataSource = vendors.first
        }
    }

    var dataSource: PoVendorModel? {
        didSet {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

The `button` actions for `next` and `previous` buttons goes like,

```
@IBAction func onTapNextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let nextIndex = min(currentIndex+1, vendors.count)
    if nextIndex != currentIndex {
        self.dataSource = vendors[nextIndex]
        currentIndex = nextIndex
    }
}

@IBAction func onTapPreviousButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let previousIndex = max(0, currentIndex-1)
    if previousIndex != currentIndex {
        self.dataSource = vendors[previousIndex]
        currentIndex = previousIndex
    }
}
```